# Problema com a criação de um novo aplicativo Angular

Tags: node.js, angular

Olá, boa tarde a todos da comunidade.

Inicie um novo projeto para desenvolvimento de uma aplicação que estou pretendendo desenvolver, mas ao dar o comando de criar um novo app angular, que é: ng new my-app (ou ng new --g my-app) o que ocorre o seguinte erro:

```
 High            Arbitrary File Overwrite
 Package         tar
 Dependency of   @angular-devkit/build-angular [dev]
 Path            @angular-devkit/build-angular > node-sass > node-gyp > tar
 More info       https://nodesecurity.io/advisories/803
```

Já tentei de várias forma solucionar o problema, mas não obtive successo.
Alguém sabe como faço para solucionar este problema?

Comment: baixa o node latest e atualiza o npm com: npm i npm

Answer (score 1):

Verificando no link que está indicado no erro, o pacote `tar` está desatualizado.

Seria uma boa tentar atualizar o `npm` ou reinstalar o pacote `tar` através do comando `npm i tar`.

Answer (score 0):

[Foi corrigido está vulnerabilidade](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/14138).

Delete a pasta`node_modules` e o `package-lock.json`,em seguida execute os comandos:

1. `npm install`
2. `npm audit`
3. `npm audit fix`
4. `npm audit`

Irá aparecer `found 0 vulnerabilities`, problema corrigido.